# Using custom auto refresh js code makes conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, buddypress

When I start using this snippet for auto refreshing a block with ajax a confliction happens with "like"ing activities on buddypress:

**myscr.js**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    function update() {
      jQuery("#notice").html('Updating...'); 
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://domain.com/activity',
        data: "recentac=true",
        //timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data) {
          jQuery("#recent-activities").html(data);
          jQuery("#notice").html(''); 
          window.setTimeout(update, 20000);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          jQuery("#notice").html('Error in connection');
          window.setTimeout(update, 5000);
        }
    });
    }
    update();
});
```

And I use `wp_enqueue_script` to print my script:

```
function auto_refresh()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('myscr', get_template_directory_uri().'/myscr.js', array("jquery"), '1.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'auto_refresh', 99);
```

Auto refereshing works and I noticed that before an auto refresh, "Like"ing works and after that it doesn't! also console doesn't show any error about it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

hey im not sure if this will help but i have read up on some no conflict and here is what it says under the link,  I copied most of the content there's extra goodies to read on the link so click it for more information.  Hope this helps

site link : http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Putting jQuery Into No-Conflict Mode
When you put jQuery into no-conflict mode, you have the option of assigning a new variable name to replace the $ alias.

```
<!-- Putting jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j( "div" ).hide();
});

// The $ variable now has the prototype meaning, which is a shortcut for
// document.getElementById(). mainDiv below is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.
window.onload = function() {
    var mainDiv = $( "main" );
}

</script>
```

In the code above, the $ will revert back to its meaning in original library. You'll still be able to use the full function name jQuery as well as the new alias $j in the rest of your application. The new alias can be named anything you'd like: jq, $J, awesomeQuery, etc.

Finally, if you don't want to define another alternative to the full jQuery function name (you really like to use $ and don't care about using the other library's $ method), then there's still another approach you might try: simply add the $ as an argument passed to your jQuery( document ).ready() function. This is most frequently used in the case where you still want the benefits of really concise jQuery code, but don't want to cause conflicts with other libraries.

```
    <!-- Another way to put jQuery into no-conflict mode. -->
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // You can use the locally-scoped $ in here as an alias to jQuery.
    $( "div" ).hide();
});

// The $ variable in the global scope has the prototype.js meaning.
window.onload = function(){
    var mainDiv = $( "main" );
}

</script>
```